# Websocket acting different on different client languages

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this **Django Python** Channels setup:

class MarketplaceConsumer(GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):
queryset = TestChannel.objects.all()
serializer_class = TestChannelSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

```
    @model_observer(TestChannel)
    async def comment_activity(self, message: TestChannelSerializer, observer=None, **kwargs):
        await self.send_json(message.data)

    @comment_activity.serializer
    def comment_activity(self, instance: TestChannel, action, **kwargs) -> TestChannelSerializer:
        '''This will return the comment serializer'''
        return TestChannelSerializer(instance)

    @action()
    async def subscribe_to_comment_activity(self, user_pk, **kwargs):
        print(user_pk) # PRINTS USER_PK PASSED THROUGH ACTION
        await self.comment_activity.subscribe()
```

When this is run through **JavaScript**, I do get the expected result, the action prints the user_pk.
[image]
However, connecting to the same WebSocket using flutter, the user_pk is not printed, meaning the action specified is not even being called.
[image]
Am I implementing this incorrectly with the **flutter** client?

```
 final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/marketplace/'));
  @override
  void initState() {
    final data = json.encode({
      'action': "subscribe_to_comment_activity",
      'request_id': Helpers.generateId(),
      'user_pk': 'PCs4o8c17xg',
    });
    channel.stream.listen((message) {
      channel.sink.add(data);
      //channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
      print(jsonDecode(message));
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out! The flutter part somehow needs acknowledgement from the backend server. At least that's what I understand.

Adding an accept method to the backend works this out.

```
 async def accept(self, **kwargs):
        await super().accept(** kwargs)
        print('connected')
        await self.comment_activity.subscribe()
```